# How to solve this 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $$\epsilon y''+yy'-y=0$$
with boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=3$.

I showed that the outer solution is $y_{in}(x)=x+2+O(\epsilon)$.

Than for the inner solution, I wish to solve the follow ODE

$$Y''(X)+Y(X) \cdot Y'(X) = 0$$

with only one boundary condition $y(0)=0$ and $X={x \over \epsilon}$.

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: Please write out the perturbation problem and what you did to get this inner equation. I ask this mainly because just specifying the inner boundary condition is not enough. You need to "create" an "outer" boundary condition through the matching of the inner and outer solutions. So without seeing the outer solution, we can't tell you how to fully specify the inner solution.

Comment: Also, according to Wolfram the solutions to your equation are either constant, or hyperbolic tangents. (From the point of view of perturbation theory, this is not that surprising; think of how the graph of $\tanh(Mx)$ looks for large $M$.) So you could check this by considering $y=A\tanh(Bx+C)$ and see what you get.

Comment: @Ian I did use mathematica to solve it and found the full solution to the problem. However this is an assignment question, so I want to put in as many detail as possible. I can't recall how to solve this type of ODE from early calculus class and can't find anything that is useful from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how I would derive this result from first principles. It's sort of clear from just checking it: with $\tanh$ you differentiate to get $\text{sech}^2$. Then with $\text{sech}^2$ you differentiate and get a multiple of $\text{sech}^2 \tanh$, which is of the sort you want. Now you just have to deal with scaling and translation. But I don't see how you would come up with that (except by knowing that $\tanh$ is the sort of function that you want out of an inner boundary layer problem).

Comment: Actually, here's one place to start: $y y' = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} y^2$. So $y''+y y'=\frac{d}{dx} \left ( y' + \frac{1}{2} y^2 \right )$. Now the new equation is separable, I think.

Comment: I studied a very similar ode when solving a nonlinear evolutionary equation (your case with $t\to -t$) then I found a very close approximation up to scaling of the diffusion error term..of an autowave solution of the sawtooth form. Also, in my case the phase plot was of concentric  orbits about $y=y'=0$ and a change in behavior as you transition between $y' = 1$. for what its worth..so where did the equation come from?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach:

$$y'' + yy' = 0 \\
y'' + \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} y^2 = 0 \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left ( y' + \frac{1}{2} y^2 \right ) = 0 \\
y' + \frac{1}{2} y^2 = C_1 \\$$

This is a Riccati type equation. Apparently, by a standard technique which is specific to Riccati equations (cf. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html), we can let $y=\frac{2z'}{z}$, so that

$$y'=\frac{2zz''-2z'^2}{z^2}=\frac{2z''}{z}-\frac{2z'^2}{z^2}.$$

Hence $y'+\frac{1}{2} y^2 = \frac{2z''}{z}$, so we have

$$\frac{2z''}{z} = C_1.$$

This is not hard to solve; then you back-substitute to find $y$. The process is a little bit easier if you write $z$ in terms of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$, because given $y(0)=0$ you have $z'(0)=0$, so actually $z$ is a $\cosh$ function, and so $y$ is a $\tanh$ function.

Answer (score 1):

1. The outer expansion: Let $y=y_0+O(\epsilon)$. Then we have
   $$
   \epsilon(y_0''+O(\epsilon))+(y_0+O(\epsilon))(y_0'+O(\epsilon))-(y_0+O(\epsilon))=0.
   $$
   Then $O(1)$ term gives
   $$ y_0y_0'-y_0=0,y_0(1)=3 $$
   which has the solution $y_0=x+2$.
2. The inner expansion: Let $X=\frac{x}{\epsilon}$ and $Y(X)=y(\epsilon X)$. The equation becomes
   $$ Y''+YY'-\epsilon Y=0.$$
   Let $Y=Y_0+O(\epsilon)$. Then we have
   $$
   (Y_0''+O(\epsilon))+(Y_0+O(\epsilon))(Y_0'+O(\epsilon))-\epsilon(Y_0+O(\epsilon))=0, Y_0(0)=0.
   $$
   Then $O(1)$ term gives
   $$ Y_0''+Y_0Y_0'=0,Y_0(0)=0 $$
   which has the solution $Y_0=2c\tanh(cX)$ (suppose $Y'(0)=2c^2$). Here $c$ is a constant to be determined.
3. Matching: we require that the inner solution matches the outer solution, namely,
   $$ \lim_{x\to0^+}y_0(x)=\lim_{X\to\infty}Y_0(X) $$ 
   from which we have $2c=2$ or $c=1$.

In summery, the asymptotic solution as $\epsilon\to0^+$ is given by
$$ 
y(x,\epsilon)=y_0(x)+Y_0(\frac{x}{\epsilon})-Y_{overlap}=(x+2)+\tanh(\frac{x}{\epsilon})-2.
$$